# Grounding (Earthing) the power system at the South Pole

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity

I apologize for the length if this question.

The US has a Science Station at the South Pole. I worked there for a couple summers as an electrician. It is a fairly large facility. The main building can house 150 people. At the time I worked there, there was a camp set up that could house an additional 120 people. The geographic South Pole is covered in an in incredible 3 km  (2 miles) of ice. The ice is a glacier that moves approximately 9 m (30 feet) per year. The snow accumulation is approximately 23 cm (9 inches) per year although drifting around the buildings makes it seem like much more. All these figures are from memory so feel free to rake me over the coals if they are off.

The station has a US electrical system that runs at 60 hz. If memory serves me correctly, it is generated and distributed at 480 volts three phase. Many of the major science facilities are approximately 400 m (1/4 mile) from the generation. I believe some of those buildings have 4160 volt power feeders to them for voltage drop. Most of the power is transformed down to 120/208 volt three phase for utilization.

All of this is built on top of nonconductive snow that gets compressed into fairly pure, relatively nonconductive ice. There is no earth to connect the power system to. Instead, the system relies on everything being bonded together with stout copper cable. The bonding system mostly works although it seems to be prone to nuisance, transient voltages.

The way the South Pole gets water is by circulating hot water in the ice 400+ feet down to melt out a cavern of fresh, liquid water. The water is pumped out for use. Eventually the size of the cavern becomes impractical and the cavern is repurposed for waste water. Yes, they dump sewage into the glacier.

The waste water collects all sorts of conductive contaminants that no doubt makes it as conductive as we normally think of surface water being. I theorized that a grounding electrode could be placed in the large mass of wastewater that would serve as a large conductive mass. The large mass would serve as an electrical sink, helping with transient voltages and would be beneficial in the event of a fault.

The questions; How much does an earth ground function as an electrical sink and is that useful for  sources other than lightning? (The South Pole doesn't have lightning)

Could the benefits of an earth ground be simulated by some other large conductive mass?

Could a bunch of freezing and frozen sewage serve as that conductive mass?

Comment: Q1: Is "electrical sink" a term of art that electricians use? If so, what does it mean? Q2: About those nuisance transient voltages... We all know that voltage is always measured between two points. What would typically be the two points between which those voltages appeared? What would be the typical duration and magnitude of the transients?

Comment: You called me out on the misuse of what is actually an electronics term. It is a term electricians commonly use that way. The concept I'm trying to sort out is, when there is a ground fault on a grounded electrical system how much of that current returns to the source and how much is absorbed like a capacitor with one conductor (the earth) infinitely large for all practical purposes. I'm not sure if I am think about that the right way. The transient voltages presented as problems with radio equipment and damaged electronics. The South Pole also has rampant static electricity from the climate.